# I got answer as 10 from one of the sites but I didn't understand how come 10

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class A
{
    int i = 10;
} 
class B extends A
{
        int i = 20;
}
public class MainClass
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                A a = new B();
                System.out.println(a.i);
        }
}
```

I got answer as 10 from one of the sites but I didn't understand how come 10

Comment: Unlike methods, fields aren't chosen dynamically (I think)

Answer (score 2):

You got `10` because you have used the reference to `A`. If you cast it to `B` as shown below, you will get `20`.

```
class A {
    int i = 10;
}

class B extends A {
    int i = 20;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        System.out.println(a.i);
        System.out.println(((B) a).i);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
10
20
```